# Flutter app stuck on the Observatory Listening on ********************* , on VIVO Devices after an OS Update

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, devtools

Being a newbie in Flutter Development,
I am using my real device to run the flutter app in VS code through the command **flutter run**.
The app is building ,installing but the terminal says **Observatory listening on** ************************************ due to which I am not able to access the hot reload or restart functions.
Previously I have developed apps on the same device.

Current Running code is a demo code that the flutter provides (flutter create) with no changes
[Terminal is Stuck at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqSDb.png)

METHODS TRIED :

1. flutter doctor -> attached [Flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRCtu.png)
2. flutter run -v  ->  attached [flutter verbose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAHW2.png)
3. devices restarted
4. USB Cable Checked / Devices tried

Flutter run --verbose code [Complete verbose log here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k9-mqXvpSDMDS9Ib48mChTpyUHd5qOzZ/view?usp=sharing)

I may be wrong but I feel that the **dart dev tools** aren't finding the port to start in the browser due to which app is not opening in debugging mode -> **restart, reload functions aren't available.**
Or might be the case that some data may have cached up in the developer options(not logical xD).

Thank You in advance. Let me know if anything else is needed.

Comment: Do you also have vivo phone? and does the problem started appearing after a recent update?

Comment: Yes vivo phone and problem occured just after the update. Any way out ??

Comment: I have a vivo phone and I also have this problem

Comment: Me too have the same pblm after an update from today mrng, still occurs!

Comment: same happening in my vivo phone

Comment: same happening in my vivo phone too

Comment: Does anyone solved this ?

Comment: I am facing same problem with my Vivo ZX1 pro device after yesterday update,

Comment: Does anyone resolved this issue ?

Comment: Just to add to this as well, I am facing same issue and have a Vivo V2025

Comment: does anyone solve this issue?

Comment: I also have this issue, any news on it?

Comment: Having this issue now, Any resolution?

Comment: Same issue on `Vivo V21e`

Comment: Same for my Vivo phone as well.

Comment: Same with `Vivo V19`. This should be opened for answers.
This happened to me after migrating to null-safety.
Some Github resource for tracking: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82520

Comment: You need to add the qq(3002261823) of vivo's development supporter to auth debug function. Reference to the blog(https://blog.csdn.net/qq910689331/article/details/128790897 ), it's written in Chinese and translate by yourself